# Replacing NA values in data frame iteratively using another column

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

I have a data frame with about 50 overlapping columns that I need to combine across. Below is a snippet of what the data frame looks like (it is about 150 rows long and several hundred columns across)

```
ID   PAI_Q1.y  PAI_Q1.x
540     0      NA
680     1      NA
240     NA      2
330     NA      3
```

For a single column, the following code works perfectly:

```
qualtrics <- qualtrics %>% 
   mutate(PAI_Q1 = ifelse(is.na(PAI_Q1.y), PAI_Q1.x, PAI_Q1.y))
```

However, I'm having trouble writing this into a loop or a function across all of the rows that need to be converted (i.e., PAI_Q2, PAI_Q3, etc...). Below are the two attempts I've made thus far. Does anyone have suggestions for tweaks (or know of a function that exists) that let me do this basic task iteratively?

Attempt #1

```
mutate_col <- function(data, string, string.x, string.y){
  data <- data %>% mutate(string = ifelse(is.na(string.y), string.x, string.y))
}
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `string`.
```

ℹ `string = ifelse(is.na(string.y), string.x, string.y)`.
x object 'PAI_Q1.y' not found

Attempt #2

```
for (i in 1:colnames(df)){
  if(names(i) %in% list_of_cols){ #list of columns that must be combined
    y <- paste(i, ".y", sep = "")
    x <-  paste(i, ".x", sep = "")
  df <- df %>% mutate(i = ifelse(is.na(y), x, y))
  }
  
}

ID   PAI_Q1.y  PAI_Q1.x    i.1
540     0      NA          PAI.Q1.y
680     1      NA          PAI.Q1.y
240     NA      2          PAI.Q1.y
330     NA      3          PAI.Q1.y
```

Comment: Would `dplyr::coallesce()` give you what you want in one go?

Comment: It looks like you joined together two tables on "ID" and then the columns got named `*.x` and `*.y`. Is there any reason to not stack the tables instead, filter out the NA values, and then sort on ID? That or something close may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr` to change the data from wide to long, then get the data the correct format, then change back to wide format.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

qualtrics <- qualtrics %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    !ID,
    names_to = "question",
    values_to = "value",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(question = stringr::str_extract(question, "[^.]+")) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = value)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID PAI_Q1 PAI_Q2
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1   540      0      0
2   680      1      1
3   240      2      2
4   330      3      3
```

Data

```
qualtrics <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(540, 680, 240, 330),
      PAI_Q1.y = c(0, 1,
                   NA, NA),
      PAI_Q1.x = c(NA, NA, 2, 3),
      PAI_Q2.y = c(0, 1, NA, NA),
      PAI_Q2.x = c(NA, NA, 2, 3)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-4L)
  )
```

Comment: You can save a couple of lines with: `pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = c("question", "suffix"), values_to = "value", names_sep = "[.]", values_drop_na = TRUE)` or something like that. Not sure if there is a way to make it even shorter and drop the "suffix" column